# What does this statement tell please explain if(!(!x) && x)

Tags: c

What does this statement tell please explain `if(!(!x) && x)`

```
#include<stdio.h> 
 
int  main(){
   int x=5, y=10;

   if(!(!x) && x)
     printf("%d",x); 
   else   
    printf("%d",y); 

  return   0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`if(!(!x) && x)` is equivalent to `if(!!x && x)`.

`!!x` is 1 if `x` is non-zero and 0 if `x` is zero.

Furthermore, the expression simplifies to `(!!x)` since `&& x` is a tautology as `x` is a non-`volatile` `int` type. But this collapsing the value to either 0 or 1 is exactly the behaviour of the `if` conditional, so the `if` simplifies to `if (x)`.

Comment: `due to the short-circuiting property of &&` it does not simplify because of that. If `!!x` is 1 second part of the && is needed. In this trivial example the second check will be optimized out by the compiler. but amke the control variable volatile https://godbolt.org/z/TpETQj or compile without optimisations

Comment: Ratifying P__J__’s comment: I think you mean that, in `!!x & x`, the second operand of `&` is not evaluated because we know `x` is 5, so the first operand is true. Saying “the expression simplifies” is somewhat misleading; the expression is not simplified in the sense of being reduced by optimization or analysis of the expression alone. When the known value of `x` is considered as well, the expression may in fact be reduced in compile-time optimization, but, if so, it should be reduced fully to “true,” not just to `!!x`.

Answer (score 3):

In c, true and false are 1 and 0 respectively.

```
!(!x)
```

If x is zero, then (!x) evaluates as true (1), then !(true) evaluates as false.

The if statement is always false in such case.

```
if(!(!x) && x)
```

However, if x was non-zero, then !!x is true

```
true && true
```

You could simplify this if statement with

```
if(x)
```

---

Looking at the assembly generated by GCC 10.1 on https://godbolt.org/z/7kwDdJ

```
xor     eax, eax      // eax = 0
test    edi, edi      // perform bitwise & and set Zero, Positive, or Negative flag
sete    al            // Sets lower 8-bits in eax to 1 if the zero flag is set or to 0 otherwise.
ret
```

In short, GCC is reducing `if(!(!x) && x)` to `if (x & x)`

Comment: although true is one, any non zero value is, in fact, true. In C. :-)

Comment: @LeoSmith where did I say only 1 is true? I said the other way around (that true is 1) :). It could have been evaluated as true from `-5` or `19331`

Comment: it is only the  if the x is not side effects prone

Answer (score 0):

`!` is the not operator. It reverses 1 to 0 and vice versa. In your problem `!(!x)`
evaluates to x and  so `(!(!x) && x)` will evauate to a true condition so x will be printed

Answer (score 0):

In **C** language non-zero values are considered *True* and zero(0) is considered *False*. On the other hand, **Logical Not (!)** operator determines the opposite of something. For example: in your code, x = 5, So the value of **!x** will be 0, because x = 5 means the variable x holds a true value. So, not true = false = 0. Then the value of !(!x) = !(false/0) = not false = true = 1.
**Remember that,** logical NOT(!) operator doesn't change the value.

So ultimately **!(!x)** means *true*.
if(!(!x) && x) = if(true && true) = if(true)
This is why, *if block* will be executed.